# How to update the array object value on the basis of index in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wants to update the array object value on the basis of the index in Javascript ES6 with the following json data and javascript code. I want to update the description.

```
 const products = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Milk Powder",
    "qty": 2,
    "unitprice": 200,
    "totalamount": 400
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "description": "Air Conditioner",
    "qty": 5,
    "unitprice": 500,
    "totalamount": 2500
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "description": "RC Cars",
    "qty": 30,
    "unitprice": 800,
    "totalamount": 24000
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "description": "Down Coat",
    "qty": 2,
    "unitprice": 300,
    "totalamount": 600
}
]
```

Javascript Code

```
const handleProductName = (e, index) =>{
   const item = [...products,[index].description=e.target.value]
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid updating the original array/objects? Otherwise, `products[index].description = e...` could be what you need to use

Comment: Not able to do this...

Comment: Why not? That’s one way to do it.

Comment: can you post answer! @DaveNewton

Comment: getting this error - Cannot assign to read only property 'description' of object

Comment: @evolutionxbox, what are you saying? :p This question is not about updating to ES6..

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan, what are you trying to achieve? I suppose you have an input field that has the *handleProductName* handler. But what does it do? Where does this index come from?

Comment: handleProductName is an onClick event on input on the table. and i am looping products on table.

Comment: @Wimanicesir trying to update it using [...products,[index].description=e.target.value]. but its creating new object in array

Comment: You should look into the function splice :)

Comment: You don’t have a POJsO if you’re getting a message about a property that can’t be updated. Without much context we’re just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it appears as though you want to avoid updating the original array of objects (ie: treat it as immutable/read only). Since products is an array and not an object it doesn’t make much sense to spread it into an object like you’re currently doing. I would suggest however using a newer method (introduced after ES6, in ES2023), called [.with()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/with) which allows you to update an index from your array but produces a new array, without touching the original:

```js
const updatedProducts = products.with(index, {...products[index], description: e.target.description});
```

If you can’t support with yet, it is easy enough to [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#change-array-by-copy) if needed as well.

Comment: I have to admit the question itself has not a lot of quality. However, only you ask about whether the original was has to be mutated or not, but this never gets an answer..

Comment: @Wimanicesir Yeah, agreed. They did reply saying they were “not able to do this” and posted this error “Cannot assign to read only property 'description' of object”, so I’m guessing they have something like TS or eslint, or perhaps frozen their objects, giving them this error (I’ve seen this type of error before for some users who use react where they’re not allowed to mutate state directly)